# Selecting the shortest column per group in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So my table has an NVARCHAR(MAX) column where each entry (path) is prefixed with an identifier, for example, with N identifiers:

```
id-1\path\to\stuff
id-1\different\path
...
id-2\path\to\stuff
id-2\different\path
...
id-N\path\to\stuff
id-N\different\path
...
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a query to select one row per identifier, and each row would be chosen by having the shortest path in it's identifier group, including the other columns in the row.

So the result of the query would be N rows total, one row per identifier, with the rows being chosen on the basis of the shortest overall path length.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to count the backslashes.   You can do that with `len()` and `replace()`.  So:

```
select t.*
from  (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by len) as seqnum
       from t cross apply
            ( values (len(path) - len(replace(path, '/', ''))) ) v(len)
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `cross apply` is just a convenient way of naming an expression for the query.  It calculates the number of slashes ("length of path") by comparing the lengths of the path with and without slashes.  The `row_number()` then orders the rows for eah `id` based on `len`, with the shortest `len` getting a value of `1`.

Comment: This works great, but I'm not experienced in SQL, would you mind explaining how this accomplished what I asked so I can understand? Thanks!